# .net core angular 6 app ngx-bootstrap not working error: 'Cannot GET /'

Tags: .net-core, angular6, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to get ngx-bootstrap (Firstly the TooltipModule) to work in my .net core 2.1 angular 6 app (I have upgraded from angular 5 to 6).
I have followed instructions from [ngx-bootstrap:tooltip](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/?gclid=CjwKCAjwqarbBRBtEiwArlfEIMJcLZjRDHEFNYu0r7Y72Ybm9yOJKxhnCKT0BLyKHlAc665IgovSuxoCZcsQAvD_BwE#/tooltip).

So i do the following steps:-

```
1. npm install ngx-bootstrap --save 

2. // RECOMMENDED (doesn't work with system.js)
   import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap/tooltip';
   // or
   import { TooltipModule } from 'ngx-bootstrap';

   @NgModule({
     imports: [TooltipModule.forRoot(),...]
   })
   export class AppModule(){}

3. <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"
       tooltip="Vivamus sagittis lacus vel augue laoreet rutrum faucibus.">
     Simple demo
   </button>
```

Then I start the app and i get the error on the browser that reads "Cannot GET /"
If i remove the TooltipModule from the AppModules Imports then the app loads normally.

When i check developer console it says: "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 () localhost/:1"

I'm using Angular CLI: 6.1.1 and Node: 10.7.0 please help.

here is my angular.json file:-

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "SyXRiskManagement": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "progress": true,
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css",
              "node_modules/@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "testing": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.test.ts"
                }
              ]
            },
            "serve": {
              "extractCss": true
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SyXRiskManagement:build:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "SyXRiskManagement:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "SyXRiskManagement:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/assets"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "SyXRiskManagement-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e",
      "sourceRoot": "e2e",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "SyXRiskManagement:serve"
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "SyXRiskManagement",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "css"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I just saw that in my packages.json file theres no ngx-bootstrap there and in my node_modules folder theres no ngx-bootstrap folder. Could this be the fault

Answer (score 0):

Ok so i managed to figure out the problem. I feel really stupid. I was running npm install ngx-bootstrap --save in the wrong folder. so i cd to the correct folder which was name-of-my-app-folder/ClientApp run the command and package.json shows ngx-bootstrap there and node_modules now has the ngx-bootstrap folder and importing the module works:)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/schematics
```

update package.json:

```
"@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0-alpha.0",
```

update app.module.ts (in imports):

```
NgbModule.forRoot()
```

update angular.json (in styles):

```
        {"input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"}
```